# Specifying a Client to use with dask.config

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

The new Dask configuration encourages the use of a named `scheduler`. This works well for threads, multiprocessing, etc. It also deprecates the use `get`, which is reasonable. However it does raise the following question.

If one has a few different Dask Distributed Clients, which could be used for a computation, how does one pick a single Client to use within a context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of `dask.__version__ == 0.18.1` there isn't a solid answer for this.  There are two functional answers today, but it's not clear how this will resolve itself in the future.

1. Keep using `get=`

   ```
   with dask.config.set(get=my_preferred_client.get):
       ...
   ```
2. Use `distributed.client.temp_default_client`

   ```
   from distributed.client import temp_default_client
   with temp_default_client(my_preferred_client):
       ...
   ```

However I wouldn't expect either of these methods to survive forever.  There has been talk of building another protocol around schedulers, but this work has not been done (as of 2018-06-29, as always, you should check documentation for up-to-date answers).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Think we are using some mixture of both currently.

As a side note, also saw `distributed.client.ensure_default_get`. Would this be a reasonable option?

ref: https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/1.22.0/distributed/client.py#L3617-L3619

Comment: I don't know.  As above, I wouldn't want to depend on any of these mechanisms.  I don't think that we've decided on a standard way to do this forever.  Short term any of them should be fine though.

Comment: Ok, raised issue ( https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3708 ) to figure out a long term mechanism for this functionality.